# Linq to SQL with multiple Unions

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a linq union statement that has been giving me some trouble and I can't see where the issue is.  Any help would be appreciated.

The error is....
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I know the error means that I am selecting different amounts of elements in one of the linq statements, but I've examined this query extensively and I haven't been able to see that as the issue.

```
(From m In db.mainIncidents _
                                    Join r In db.rcas On r.reliabilityID Equals m.reliabilityID _
                                    Join team In db.rcaInvestigationTeams On team.rcaID Equals r.rcaID _
                                    Join user In db.sysUsers On team.teamMemberID Equals user.sysUserID _
                                    Where m.reliabilityID = reliabilityID _
                                    And team.deleted = False _
                                    Select name = user.firstName & " " & user.lastName & " (" & user.id.ToUpper & ")", _
                                    email = user.id & "@test.com", _
                                    user.phone, _
                                    isSponsor = "No", _
                                    isFacilitator = "No", _
                                    isAssetTeamLead = "No").Union _
                               (From m In db.mainIncidents _
                                    Join r In db.rcas On r.reliabilityID Equals m.reliabilityID _
                                    Join at In db.sysUsers On r.assetTeamLeadID Equals at.sysUserID _
                                    Where m.reliabilityID = reliabilityID _
                                    Select name = at.firstName & " " & at.lastName & " (" & at.id.ToUpper & ")", _
                                    email = at.id & "@test.com", _
                                    at.phone, _
                                    isSponsor = "No", _
                                    isFacilitator = "No", _
                                    isAssetTeamLead = "Yes").Union _
                              (From m In db.mainIncidents _
                                    Join r In db.rcas On r.reliabilityID Equals m.reliabilityID _
                                    Join f In db.sysUsers On r.facilitatorID Equals f.sysUserID _
                                    Where m.reliabilityID = reliabilityID _
                                    Select name = f.firstName & " " & f.lastName & " (" & f.id.ToUpper & ")", _
                                    email = f.id & "@test.com", _
                                    f.phone, _
                                    isSponsor = "No", _
                                    isFacilitator = "Yes", _
                                    isAssetTeamLead = "No").Union _
                              (From m In db.mainIncidents _
                                    Join r In db.rcas On r.reliabilityID Equals m.reliabilityID _
                                    Join s In db.sysUsers On r.sponsorID Equals s.sysUserID _
                                    Where m.reliabilityID = reliabilityID _
                                    Select name = s.firstName & " " & s.lastName & " (" & s.id.ToUpper & ")", _
                                    email = s.id & "@test.com", _
                                    s.phone, _
                                    isSponsor = "No", _
                                    isFacilitator = "No", _
                                    isAssetTeamLead = "No")
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this statement either - Have you tried removing individual Union statements to try and narrow down which one is causing the issue?

Comment: Yea, I've tried a bunch of different combination's of unions and removing the selected elements as well.  I'm at home now and don't have access to the project but I'll take another stab at it tomorrow.  thank you for affirm that i am not insane though.  I spent over an hour on this one statement that took only a couple minutes to actually write.  One other thing I did not think of trying is running the statements as individual queries and aggregating them into a datatable.  This might shed some light as well.

Comment: Have you tried assigning each component of the Union to its own local (with type inference: type var) and then taking the Union over the locals. This will allow you to examine the types of each of the component expressions to see which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the issue in the query. I've used LINQPad and run your query against an adhoc object model and it runs without complaint.

The only thing I can suggest is to remove the repetition. Hopefully then the error will no longer be there.

Here's my factoring.

I do a single `db.sysUsers` query:

```
Dim users =
    From u In db.sysUsers
    Select New With { _
        .userId = u.id, _
        .name = u.firstName & " " & u.lastName & " (" & u.id.ToUpper & ")", _
        .email = u.id & "@test.com", _
        .phone = u.phone }
```

I do a single query on `db.mainIncidents` & `db.rcas`:

```
Dim rcas =
    From m In db.mainIncidents _
    Where m.reliabilityID = reliabilityID _
    Join r In db.rcas On r.reliabilityID Equals m.reliabilityID _
    Select r
```

And here's the best part, a `Role` query:

```
Dim roles =
    From r In rcas _
    From role in ( _
    { _
        New With { .userId = r.assetTeamLeadID, .role = "AssetTeamLead" }, _
        New With { .userId = r.facilitatorID, .role = "Facilitator" }, _
        New With { .userId = r.sponsorID, .role = "Sponsor" } _
    }).Concat(From team In db.rcaInvestigationTeams _
        Where team.deleted = False _
        Where team.rcaID = r.rcaID _
        Select New With { .userId = team.teamMemberID, .role = "TeamMember" }) _
    Select role
```

And now, the final query:

```
Dim query =
    From u In users _
    Join r In roles On u.userId Equals r.userId _
    Select u.name, u.email, u.phone, _
    isSponsor = If(r.role = "Sponsor", "Yes", "No"), _
    isFacilitator = If(r.role = "Facilitator", "Yes", "No"), _
    isAssetTeamLead = If(r.role = "AssetTeamLead", "Yes", "No")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I would have never thought to solve this problem that way.